# How to add a package controller to a project created with FXML JavaFX Maven Archetype (Gluon) in Netbeans 12?

Tags: maven, javafx, gluon

When I create a project with FXML JavaFX Maven Archetype (Gluon) in Netbeans 12, I get the following hierarchy of files in the project:

```
└── helloworld
    ├── App.java
    ├── PrimaryController.java
    └── SecondaryController.java
```

This is all right, but I would like to get the following structure, instead:

```
└── helloworld
    └── controller
        ├── App.java
        ├── PrimaryController.java
        └── SecondaryController.java
```

```
└── resources
    └── com
        └── whatever
            └── fx
                └── helloworld
                    └── fxml
                        ├── primary.fxml
                        └── secondary.fxml
```

I follow these steps:

1. Add a package controller to `helloworld` package.
   Add a package fxml in `helloworld` package of resources
2. Put `App.java`, `PrimaryController.java`, and `SecondaryController.java` in the package controller.
   Put `primary.fxml` and `secondary.fxml` in package fxml

### Code Java

```java
public class App extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("fxml/primary"), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

```java
public class PrimaryController {

    @FXML
    private void switchToSecondary() throws IOException 
    {
        App.setRoot("fxml/secondary");
    }
}
```

```java
public class SecondaryController {

    @FXML
    private void switchToPrimary() throws IOException {
        App.setRoot("fxml/primary");
    }
```

3. In `Module-info.java`, replace

```java
opens com.whatever.fx.helloworld to javafx.fxml;
exports com.whatever.fx.helloworld;
```

with

```java
opens com.whatever.fx.helloworld.controller to javafx.fxml;
exports com.whatever.fx.helloworld.controller;
```

4. In `pom.xml`, replace

```xml
<configuration>
    <mainClass>com.whatever.fx.helloworld.App</mainClass>
</configuration>
```

with

```xml
<configuration>
    <mainClass>com.whatever.fx.helloworld.controller.App</mainClass>
</configuration>
```

5. In `primary.fxml`, replace

```xml
fx:controller="com.whatever.fx.helloworld.PrimaryController">
```

with

```xml
fx:controller="com.whatever.fx.helloworld.controller.PrimaryController">
```

6. In `secondary.fxml`, replace

```xml
x:controller="com.whatever.fx.helloworld.SecondaryController">
```

with

```xml
fx:controller="com.whatever.fx.helloworld.controller.SecondaryController">
```

However, after following all of the above steps, I get the following error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at com.whatever.fx.helloworld/com.whatever.fx.helloworld.controller.App.loadFXML(App.java:31)
    at com.whatever.fx.helloworld/com.whatever.fx.helloworld.controller.App.start(App.java:20)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.whatever.fx.helloworld.controller.App
Command execution failed.
```

Comment: You didn't mention updating the path used by the `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: unrelated: don't use static scope, instead pass parameters

Comment: @Slaw I have updated the question wiht Code Java and resources hierarchy. At the begin i used only name fxml file `primary` and `secondary` y now i'm using `fxml/primary` and `fxml/secondary`